# how to use specials characters in the variables declaration in java?

Tags: java, sql

Is it possible to declare java attribute name using specials characters, exemple:

```
private String var/name;
private int one+one;
```

I ask this question because I need to retrieve data from DB, whose the name of one colomn is `annoces/status`, And I need to use sql query (not hql or criteria)

Comment: You seem to be asking two unrelated questions here. What is the relationship between the variable name and query column name, and what does it matter if a column name (essentially a string) has a slash in it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: @Ic  to get data I use `bbr.sendQuery("Select Status, Name,Annonces/Sta, From table ",MyObject.class);` then I need to create all this variables in in `myObject.class`

Comment: What database are you using - I don't know of any that would allow you to define a column name such as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do that:

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — **an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits**, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character "_". The convention, however, is to always begin
>   your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "_". Additionally, the
>   dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>   find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>   dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>   similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>   technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
>   practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.

I don't understand why you need that though.

Edit

You can use something like bbr.sendQuery("Select Status, Name, **Annonces/Sta AS annoncesSta**, From table ",MyObject.class); with **AS** you can change the name of the column that you receive in the result. So your attribute in the java class can be "annoncesSta".

Anyway is wired to have column names with "/", best practices for names are:

- AnnoncesSta
- announces_sta

And most mappers handle those names automatically.

Comment: because to get data I use `bbr.sendQuery("Select Status, Name,Annonces/Sta, From table ",MyObject.class);` the I need to create all this variables in  in `myObject.class`

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no need to name the Java variables same as the column names in some table in some database.

If you are trying to store column values in some Map then map keys can have any special character you want.

Comment: what does it mean when we found `/` in sql query, exemple `Select Status, Name,Annonces/Sta, From table`

Comment: Sorry just noted your comment, I believe you've already got the answer from folks here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you are asking - as detailed by others. My suggested solution is to sort out the column names in your database so that they follow normal standards and then you can use the same names in java.

By normal standards I mean:

```
alphanumeric characters or the following special characters: $ _ #
```